# CodeIgniter: $data access in all views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to access $data[] variables in whole site, in all views. I created TestLeangue controller and assign some values to $data but in all views say that variable is not defined

```
    class TestLanguage extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load("menu","english");
    }

    function index() {
        $data['shipping'] = $this->lang->line('menu_shipping');
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation', $data);
    }
}
```

I echo and say that I have undefined variable.

```
<?= $shipping; ?>
```

Comment: use **$shipping** on template/naigation , because when you are passing $data['xyz'], It will be $xyz that you will get at view,and not $data.

Comment: Yes, I echo-it like this <?= $shipping; ?> but maybe i have not connected something with my controller or model, i don't know, i just started to use codeIgniter

Comment: first check that you have data in $data['shipping'], and also mention the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Index of $data as a variable name (**$shipping**), to get the value that you have assigned as `$data['shipping']`

**Controller**

```
class TestLanguage extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load("menu","english");
    }

    function index() {
        $data['shipping'] = $this->lang->line('menu_shipping');
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation', $data);
    }
}
```

**View :templates/navigation**

```
<?php 
print_r($shipping);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use that data like a global variable?

```
class MY_Controller extends ...
{
    protected $data = [];
}
```

Then everytime when you extend your custom controller you will have access to the general data.

```
class MyCustomStackOverflowController extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->view('index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use `$this->data` to load it with general information for current controller like:

```
class MyCustomStackOverflowController extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['title'] = 'Stackoverflow';
    }

    public function index()
    {
           ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It works only when I write the controller in url `localhost/TestLanguage` but not on index page or other

Comment: Did you declare the route to `application/config/routes.php`?